# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number in Django distance

Tags: python, django, openlayers

I tried to get the value from my template which is `kmdistance` but it returns an error when I view the page.

Here's the views.py

```
def display_maps(request):
    #bases for city proper
    pnt = ButuanMaps.objects.get(clandpin='162-03-0001-017-33').geom

    #landproperty__sownerid__id=5 is for government user
    kmdistance = request.GET.get("kmtocity", None)
    mysection = (request.GET.get("mysection", None))
    query_section = Section.objects.all().order_by('id')
    ...
    query_maps = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(landproperty__sownerid__id=5, geom__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=kmdistance)), ssectionid__id=mysection)
    ...
```

Here's the template.html

```
  <select name="kmtocity" class="form-control">
      <option type="text" value="empty">Select Km. away from City Proper</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
   </select>
```

It works fine when I tried putting the value in distance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are defaulting to a None value when the `kmdistance` is not found in the `request.GET` directory here

> `kmdistance = request.GET.get("kmtocity", None)`

As such, when you convert None to a float later, it throws up an error

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

To overcome this, wherever you are converting to float, just check that the kmdistance value exists, and then convert it to float

```
if kmdistance is not None:
    kmdistance = float(kmdistance)
```

Alternatively, use a different default value, like 0 instead of `None` (though 0 kmdistance may imply wrong value for km distance, so you can use another default value like 100 which works for you)

Comment: Ok, so how to let Django know that it is float or number? I removed   `None`, but it throws up the same error.

Comment: @SachiTekina In this statement, `query_maps = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(landproperty__sownerid__id=5, geom__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=kmdistance)), ssectionid__id=mysection)`, you use `geom__distance_lte`, which means it will be comparing with distance. It should be here that the conversion to float must be happening internally. This seems like a filed you must pass, so defaulting to a suitably big value would be a better option here.

Comment: Thanks! I thinks I'll just set the default distance to a higher value because I just want to fetch all the geoms if the user did not select the distance.