# TypeError: Field 'price' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>

Tags: django, django-models, typeerror

I have that exception"TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'FloatField'" even thought i deleted the price field and runned makemigrations , how???

Comment: did you run migrate after makemigrations?

Comment: The line where the logic is there for `price` in your views, put a if statement just before `if price is not None:`. Not sure if you're having this problem? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735516/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-in-django-distance